# Font size looks bigger in Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, highcharts, r-highcharter

When I use highchart in both Chrome and Firefox, the font size appears quite bigger in Firefox. Below is one example -

In Chrome -
[image]

In Firefox -
[image]

How can I make font size appears exactly same in two browser?

Any pointer will be appreciated.

**Adding one more example -**

**R code -**

```
Data = data.frame(x = round(rnorm(20) * 100, 2), y = round(rnorm(20) * 100, 2), z = letters[1:20])
 hchart(Data, "scatter", hcaes(x, y)) %>%
   hc_yAxis(
     plotLines = list(
       list(color = "#252525",
            width = 2,
            value = 0)
     )
   )
```

Plot on Firefox -
[image]

Plot on Chrome -
[image]

I am using MacOS as operating system

Comment: The sample Highcharts chart written in JavaScript doesn't have this problem: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0pbeym97/
Could you provide your code and steps I need to do to open your R chart in browsers? I will be able to test it

Comment: I have added one more example highlighting the issue and corresponding R code. Firefox fonts appear bolder and thicker for same plot

Comment: This is often caused by having the zoom settings different in the two browsers rather than anything to do with the code.

Comment: @Quentin - I would be happy if that was the case. However I checked both browsers' zoom setting and both are 100%. Did you run above code in your system and checked if they were different?